Can I split a group (1 circuit) of neutrals in 2 inside a 4 gang box
I have a 4 gang box with 7 neutral wires twisted with a nut, it's all 1 circuit on 1 breaker, I need to add a new wire to it, but I don't have a bigger nut, can I split that in 2 and link them together with another wire? I made a sketch:


Yes, that is perfectly fine. Electrically it is the same thing whether in one, two or even three groups. Similar situations happen when adding a neutral to a switch. For example, if this box has three regular switches that are replaced with smart or motion sensor or timer or other "neutral required"  switches, then three pigtails will need to be added, and sometimes the easiest way to do that is to add another wire nut with a group of wires.
It is important to watch for box fill. A box with 7 neutrals also has 7 hot and/or switched hot wires, and possibly even more wires if there are 3-way switches or other special devices, and it may have several devices (switches, receptacles, etc.) in the same box. Box fill gets a bit complicated, and sometimes a box will start out with plenty of space and then have problems because someone keeps adding "just one more little circuit". However, the box fill rules generally ignore the connection methods (e.g., wire nuts vs. Wago connectors vs. chaining through receptacles).

Yep, no problem doing that at all.  Though unless it's a huge wirenut, I'd guess that the original one with 7 was probably overfilled to begin with.  Just make sure that the wire linking the two wire nuts is at least the same gauge as the others and is an approved neutral color of insulation.
